# How to mask edge_index with train_mask in PYG?

Tags: machine-learning, graph, pytorch-geometric

How can I mask the edge_index so that it only contains edge connections of train nodes before passing in to a GCN model, in order to prevent data leakage between test nodes and train nodes.

```
import torch
import torch_geometric
from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv

# Assuming you have a graph with node features and training labels
edge_index = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 1, 2],
                           [1, 0, 2, 1]], dtype=torch.long)
x = torch.tensor([[-1], [0], [1]], dtype=torch.float)
y = torch.tensor([1,1,1], dtype=torch.long)

train_mask = [True, True, False] # Boolean mask indicating the training nodes

data = torch_geometric.data.Data(x=x, y=y, edge_index=edge_index)
# Apply mask to input data
x_train = data.x[train_mask]
edge_index_train = **???**


# Create the GCNConv layer
conv = GCNConv(in_channels, out_channels)
# Perform forward pass only on training nodes
out = conv(x_train, edge_index_train)

# Perform further computations with the output
```

For e.g. How to replace “???” in above code?

Do people usually pass train nodes separately in forward pass and neighbourhood aggregation of the model, in order to prevent data leakage?